# Андроид. Java. Как программно изменить иконку приложения и его название?

Tags: java, android, icon

Заметил, что у стандартного календаря андроид реализована следующая функция: каждый день, в зависимости от числа месяца меняется иконка. Т.е., если сегодня 1 число, то на иконке будет изображена цифра 1, если 31-ое, то цифра 31 соответственно.

Вопрос: как такое реализовать самому?
Вопрос 2: можно ли сделать возможным программное изменения названия приложения? Если да, то как реализовать?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Добавляем разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Добавляем два метода:

```
private void shortcutAdd(String name, int number) {
// Intent to be send, when shortcut is pressed by user ("launched")
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Play.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PLAY);

// Create bitmap with number in it -> very default. You probably want to give it a more stylish look
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(0xFF808080); // gray
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setTextSize(50);
new Canvas(bitmap).drawText(""+number, 50, 50, paint);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

// Decorate the shortcut
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);

// Inform launcher to create shortcut
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}



private void shortcutDel(String name) {
// Intent to be send, when shortcut is pressed by user ("launched")
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Play.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PLAY);

// Decorate the shortcut
Intent delIntent = new Intent();
delIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
delIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);

// Inform launcher to remove shortcut
delIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(delIntent);
}
```

В конце вешаем слушателей

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.test);
findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        shortcutAdd("changeIt!", count);
    }
});
findViewById(R.id.increment).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        shortcutDel("changeIt!");
        count++;
        shortcutAdd("changeIt!", count);
    }
});
}
```

Оригинал ответа [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)